# Unity application non-interactive after unfocusing

Tags: unity, games, focus, responsiveness

Whether windowed, borderless or in fullscreen, after changing focus from a non-steam unity game to another application (or just the desktop), the game becomes non-interactive. Nothing can be clicked on, however, depending on the game, the UI might still responds to the mouse position (elements will light up etc.)

- Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS 64-bit
- 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i3-1115G4 @ 3.00GHz × 4
- Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (TGL GT2)
- Windowing System Wayland